# What does `expires -1` mean in NGINX `location` directive?

Tags: caching, nginx, cache-control

Given the sample `location` example below, what does `-1` mean for `expires`? Does that mean "never expires" or "never caches"?

```
# cache.appcache, your document html and data
location ~* \.(?:manifest|appcache|html?|xml|json)$ {
  expires -1;
  access_log logs/static.log;
}
```

https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx/blob/b935688c2b/h5bp/location/expires.conf

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to [nginx manual](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires), this directive adds the `Expires` and `Cache-Control` HTTP header to the response.

Value `-1` means these headers are set as:

> `Expires:`  *current time minus 1 second*
>
> `Cache-Control: no-cache`

So in summary it instructs the browser not to cache the document.

Answer (score 8):

If `expires -1` is used, it means that these pages are never cached.  The `expire` directive instructs the browser to expire file cache after a certain amount of time (or at a certain time).  If a negative value is given, there is no caching.

Comment: That is not true, it has nothing to do with caching in nginx itself. It just adds a header for the browser - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_headers_module.html#expires

Comment: Correct it is browser caching - my mistake.  I've updated my answer.  I am not sure what your separate answer adds though - essentially setting expire to a negative value means there is no caching.

Answer (score 1):

Neither existing answer is strictly true. Setting `expires: -1;` does indeed make nginx add `Cache-Control: no-cache` HTTP header. This *does not* disable caching though. Instead, this makes any cached version "expire" immediately, requiring client (browser) to re-validate cache (if any) each time.

E.g., if client has cached version of resource, it is obligated to verify by doing a request to server, which can include `If-None-Match` and/or `If-Modified-Since` headers, in which case, server can reply with `304 Not Modified` if the cached resource is still the latest.