# docker nginx:latest image - content on docker host not changing

Tags: nginx, docker

when maintaining the content and configuration on the Docker host, running:

```
docker run --name mynginx2 -v $(pwd)/var/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro \
-v $(pwd)/var/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx:ro -P -d nginx
```

I request the index.html page

```
curl http://192.168.99.100:32905  # docker-machien ip : mynginx port
```

which display correctly the default index.html

Then on my local host I modify the $(pwd)/var/www/index.html ,

```
<h1>Welcome to my nginx MODIFIED!</h1>
```

and I request again the index.html page

```
curl http://192.168.99.100:3290
```

BUT , I still get the original index.html page ... ( even after restarting the container)

what could be missing ?  thanks for any feedback..

==== UPDATE
nginx.conf

```
    user nginx;
    worker_processes  1;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
    pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }


    http {
        include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                          '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                          '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

        access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        #sendfile        on;
        sendfile        off;
        #tcp_nopush     on;

        keepalive_timeout  65;

        #gzip  on;

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    }
```

conf.d/default.conf

```
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;
        #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
        #    include        fastcgi_params;
        #}

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does your Nginx configuration file look like? Do you have caching enabled for static html files?
Try to add `expires -1;` as configuration option to the `location` of your `index.html` file.
Please have also have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30921598/what-does-expires-1-mean-in-nginx-location-directive) stackoverflow question.

Comment: thanks ..  I don't have caching enable ( unless it is default..)  I'll have a look on it

Comment: There is [an other question on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31638214/docker-restart-not-showing-the-desired-effect) about a similar issue. May be that also applies here.